# WCF client throuth proxy using username/password authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication, proxy

I have an ASP.NET web site that consumes a WCF web service, and it works perfectly.

I had to deploy it to a customer server that uses a proxy server for web access (with no authentication). To solve the issue, I needed to add the following configuration to `web.config`:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://10.1.0.50:8080" bypassonlocal="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Now I have to deploy it to another customer. He also uses proxy, but this time it's an authenticated one.

How do I configure my web site so that it uses proxy authentication (that is, provide user/password credentials) when making WCF requests?

**BONUS:** Is it possible to do it just by changing `web.config` (no code changes)?